# How to show first 10 rows and first 5 columns in R?

Tags: r

I don't know how to use the head function to meet my needs

```
small<- "Chicago_small.xlsx"
head(small, n=10)
```

Comment: You can't run `head()` directly on a `.xlsx` file. You'll need to read it in to a `data.frame` with something like `readxl::read_excel()`. Then you can use `head()` to view a snippet of desired size.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide multiple dimensions to the `n` argument of `head()`.

```r
head(mtcars, n = c(3, 2))
#>                mpg cyl
#> Mazda RX4     21.0   6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6
#> Datsun 710    22.8   4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
small[1:10, 1:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Colin Gillespie, in [Efficient R programming](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/), suggests adding the following functions to RProfile:

```
# ht == headtail
# Show the first 6 rows & last 6 rows of a data frame
ht = function(d, n=6) rbind(head(d, n), tail(d, n))
# Show the first 5 rows & first 5 columns of a data frame
hh = function(d) d[1:5, 1:5]
```

You will be able then run `hh(mtcars)` to obtain a quick summary below:

```
>> hh(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
```